# Ionic 4 ion-slides change css style of the active slide using ngClass

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ng-class, ion-slides

**EDIT: adding a stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-b2r7si

I am using ion-slides as following:

```
<ion-slides class="fullWidth" [options]="slideOptsOne" #slideWithNav
  (ionSlideDidChange)="change($event)">
  <ion-slide #status *ngFor="let array of arrays">
    <ion-col>
      {{array}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

I need to change the css style of the current active slide, like make it underlined or bold. I've done some researches and apparently I should use `[ngClass]=''` but can't know how.

I am getting the index of the active slides using:

```
change(e) {
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then(
      (index) => {
        this.currentIndex = index;
        console.log(this.currentIndex);
      }
    )
}
```

I tried:

```
  <ion-slide #status *ngFor="let array of arrays;let i=index;">
      <ion-col [ngClass]="{'activeIndex': currentIndex==array[i]}">
        {{array}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-slide>
```

And `activeIndex` style:

```
.activeIndex{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

But only one element of the array is changed of style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the activeIndex class to `currentIndex === i`. If you set it to array[i], you will get letters of the array instead of the index number you are looking for.

```
<ion-col [ngClass]="{'activeIndex': currentIndex === i}">
  {{ array }}
</ion-col>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://ionic-4-slides-css-change.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Only the first slide won't change with the activeIndex css class. You could use ionSlidesDidLoad() to handle this.