# Implementing 'active' css class on active ion-slide

Tags: typescript, angular6, ionic4

I want to change css of active slide in DOM

> .html

```
 <ion-slides>
  <ion-slide class="swiper-slide"></ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="swiper-slide active"></ion-slide> // <-- Active slide in DOM
  <ion-slide class="swiper-slide"></ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

Thanks in advance..

> .scss

```
  .slider_selected_text{
    color : #ed1a3b
    }
 .slider_unselected_text{
   }
```

Comment: Your starting point is to use `ngClass` for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146414/ionic-4-ion-slides-change-css-style-of-the-active-slide-using-ngclass?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell if you are asking for adding `active` class to the `sccs` side or dynamically adding a CSS class to `ion-slide` element. I assume you are asking for `scss` side. If not so, please let me know and I will update the answer.

You can add `.active` class to `scss` file like this:

```
.swiper-slide {

   // Assuming "slider_selected_text" is covered by "swiper-slide" class

  & .slider_selected_text{ // note that there is a space between & and class name
    color : #ed1a3b
  }

  & .slider_unselected_text{

  }

  &.active{ // note that there is NOT a space between & and class name means this will apply to the elements having both classes

     & .slider_selected_text{ // note that there is a space between & and class name
        color : #ed1a3b
      }

      & .slider_unselected_text{

      }
  }

}
```

Hope this will give you a clue.

Comment: Thank You for replying Harun.. but I want to change CSS class dynamically. On (click) of ion-Slide, that particular slide should get "slider_selected_text" CSS.
 I would be glad if you help me out with logic!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Allright I get it. I will try to update the answer.

Comment: I tried it in stackblitz, but there's a problem I could not solve now. But I will try again when I have time. In the mean time, you can search for `ionSlideDidChange` and `getActiveIndex` and set corresponding class with `ngClass`.

Comment: Thanks Harun for trying!..I am getting ActiveIndex now..but i dont know how to use that index to change CSS.

Comment: `<ion-slide class="swiper-slide" [ngClass]="{'slider_selected_text': activeIndex === 2}"></ion-slide>` I guess something like this would work. You just need to store the active index in `activeIndex` property of component. And `2` is hardcoded since you do not use `*ngFor` to generate slides. You need to change it accordingly.

Comment: Or you can do like: `<ion-slide class="swiper-slide" [ngClass]="activeIndex === 2 : 'slider_selected_text' ? 'slider_unselected_text'"></ion-slide>`